# Application + Activity + onResume == NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, lifecycle

So I am having problem I just can't get my head around in Android.

My program uses the Application class for storing globals.

In there I have the following

```
public ExampleClass SetOfExamples[];

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _appCtrl = this;
    SetOfExamples = new ExampleClass[10];
    // ARRAY IS INITED HERE - all entrys are setup.
}
```

then in an activity I have

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    appState = ((MyApplication)this.getApplication());    
    if(appState!=null)
    {
        if(appState.SetOfExamples[1]!=null)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // What do I do ???
        }
    }

}
```

Quite often in a deployed app (but never can reproduce myself!!!), it is falling into the "What do I do" portion of the code.

So why is this ? , how can my activity be resumed before myapplication create is called ?
Or is the array being created by myapplication being deallocated ? , if so how to do I prevent that - I thought it was supposed to stay there as it's part of the global application context.

ADDITIONAL INFO: This activity IS the launch activity.

Comment: You should check (appState.SetOfExamples != null && appState.SetOfExamples.length >= 2 && appState.SetOfExamples[1] != null) in that order. Makes sure the array pointer isn't null, the array index is valid, and the array at index position 1 isn't null

Comment: In the code you posted, each member of the array SetOfExamples is not being initialized, so it is no surprise that one of them is null later on.  Probably just left out of the code you chose to quote, but unless you clean up the snippet people  will only see that.

Comment: Ok, added comment. I know there should be extra protection etc. my question is though - why hasn't the oncreate in my application called ?

Comment: Seeing similar problems too. MY app relies on data persisted in my application class as well. Sometimes the onResume of my acitivties tries to grab data from the application and it comes back null. Its as if the application object has been destroyed and a new one assigned to my app.

Comment: Yeah it's such an annoying issue to deal with, I'm currently dealing with it now.  I think you're right @DeanWild, a new instance is created, however the old one is still floating around in memory, like a space turd that got away.

Comment: I know this question is old now but this recent blog post confirms our theory: http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be comparing the element [1] to null because your entire array could be null, trying to access a part of a null array will cause the exception

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment - but could be a useful answer I guess so here goes:

My problem is I have a load of data that is intialized only once in the splashscreen. I got round it by setting a boolean flag in my application which I could use to check to know for sure that my application object was populated with data. In the onCreate or onResume of all of my activities I first check this flag, if it is false then I know I have a duff application object so I just finish all of my activities till i'm at the start of my activity stack then launch my splashscreen intent - to the user it just feels like a restart. No more mystery null pointers! I'm sure there is a more elegant solution (I believe we should be persisting data to disk in the onPause - not just relying on the application object staying alive).

Worked for me - hope this can help others.